# Entity Framework 4 - Adding an existing model to an association

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have defined a relationship, which is a module can contain many courses.

I have an interface which allows you to add course to module; I have tried the code below, but this results in a new module being created in the modules table, and then added to the course

```
int moduleID = viewModel.moduleID;
course.Modules.Add( new Module { ID = moduleID } )
SaveChanges();
```

What should be the proper way?

Edit: Debugging with breakpoints show that the integer moduleID is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var module = new Module { ID = viewModel.moduleID };
// Attach first so that context doesn't track module as a new one
context.Modules.Attach(module); 
// Now make connection to attached module
course.Modules.Add(module);
context.SaveChanges();
```

As you can see I didn't need to load module from database to make a connection. This works quite good for many-to-many relations but can be more complicated in case of one-to-many relations.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new module, which means that the behaviour you're getting is normal. What you need to do is, get the `Module` object that corresponds to the `moduleID` from your data context and then add that to your course.

```
int moduleID = viewModel.moduleID;
var module = context.Modules.FirstOrDefault(m => m.ID == moduleID);
course.Modules.Add(module)
SaveChanges();
```

Hope this helps :)